# Providing Jacobian matrix does not improve optimization?

Tags: scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize-minimize

For the Rosenbrock function, I tried using scipy.optimize.least_squares with and without the Jacobian matrix. I expected the Jacobian to improve the calculation, but it did not. The results were the same:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import pandas as pd

def fun_rosenbrock(x):
    return 10 * (x[1] - x[0]**2)**2 + (1 - x[0])**2
    #return np.array([10 * (x[1] - x[0]**2), (1 - x[0])])

def jac_rosenbrock(x):
    return np.array([
        40 * x[0] ** 3 - 40 * x[0] * x[1] + 2 * x[0] - 2,
        -20 * x[0] ** 2 + 20 * x[1]
        ])

x0_rosenbrock = np.array([20, 20])
res_1 = least_squares(fun_rosenbrock, x0_rosenbrock)
res_2 = least_squares(fun_rosenbrock, x0_rosenbrock, jac_rosenbrock)

print(res_1)
print(res_2)
```

In both cases, the result looked something like below. If the result is the same, what is the point in providing the Jacobian matrix?

```
 active_mask: array([0., 0.])
        cost: 444.17831429066666
         fun: array([29.80531209])
        grad: array([77.13171789, 45.15551332])
         jac: array([[2.58785138, 1.51501562]])
     message: 'The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded.'
        nfev: 200
        njev: 194
  optimality: 77.13171788839948
      status: 0
     success: False
           x: array([-4.45416634, 19.91534845])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to be using `minimize` for a scalar function like Rosenbrock, it's not a least squares problem.
2. You can use `optimize.rosen` and `optimize.rosen_der` for the functions.
3. <s>The `jac_rosenbrock` function that you presented is not the derivative of `rosenbrock`, there should be no exponent greater than</s>
4. This optimisation halted early because the maximum number of function evaluations is capped (see the `max_nfev` kwd). It's preferable for the optimisation to converge without hitting an upper limit of function evaluations.
5. I would not necessarily expect a better solution to be found if a gradient/jacobian is supplied, I would only expect the optimisation to approach a solution in a faster manner.

EDIT: was mistaken about #3, forgot there was an x**4.

### Reply 2

(really don't use least_squares for this problem) Here's what happens when you use `minimize`. You can see that the number of function and gradient evaluations drop significantly.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import rosen, rosen_der, minimize

x0_rosenbrock = np.array([20, 20])
res_1 = minimize(rosen, x0_rosenbrock, method="trust-constr")
res_2 = minimize(rosen, x0_rosenbrock, jac=rosen_der, method="trust-constr")

print(res_1, "\n")
print(res_2)
```

```
          message: `gtol` termination condition is satisfied.
          success: True
           status: 1
              fun: 2.005482523286743e-11
                x: [ 1.000e+00  1.000e+00]
              nit: 101
             nfev: 303
             njev: 101
             nhev: 0
         cg_niter: 179
     cg_stop_cond: 1
             grad: [-1.737e-11  1.326e-10]
  lagrangian_grad: [-1.737e-11  1.326e-10]
           constr: []
              jac: []
      constr_nfev: []
      constr_njev: []
      constr_nhev: []
                v: []
           method: equality_constrained_sqp
       optimality: 1.326272425217212e-10
 constr_violation: 0
   execution_time: 0.08397698402404785
        tr_radius: 0.7739754169155908
   constr_penalty: 1.0
            niter: 101 

          message: `gtol` termination condition is satisfied.
          success: True
           status: 1
              fun: 1.4973796385498187e-16
                x: [ 1.000e+00  1.000e+00]
              nit: 72
             nfev: 72
             njev: 72
             nhev: 0
         cg_niter: 115
     cg_stop_cond: 4
             grad: [-6.575e-09 -8.941e-09]
  lagrangian_grad: [-6.575e-09 -8.941e-09]
           constr: []
              jac: []
      constr_nfev: []
      constr_njev: []
      constr_nhev: []
                v: []
           method: equality_constrained_sqp
       optimality: 8.941003493134758e-09
 constr_violation: 0
   execution_time: 0.04044008255004883
        tr_radius: 12.14199033273334
   constr_penalty: 1.0
            niter: 72
```

Comment: You're right that the least squares optimization is not the best choice for the Rosenbrock function. I just used this because it was given as an example on the scipy documentation page. The Rosenbrock function has an x^4 term, so the partial derivative should have an x^3. Regarding the pace of convergence, I would at least expect the version with the Jacobian to get closer to the real solution after the same number of evaluations.